# Shorten/Compress string in Python

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, md5

I am working on an application that stores pdf documents and a lot of info for the documents in JSON format. In order to avoid multiple loads of the same documents MD5 hashsum of the file is used as ID:

```
def create_hashsum(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as file_to_check:
        # read contents of the file
        data = file_to_check.read()    
        # pipe contents of the file through
        md5_hash = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
     return md5_hash
```

Output example: `dfa04947f231d1c8cc7e755956c90bcf`

However, ideally I want to create second, shorter human-friendly ID that is easy to remember. Requirements:

- ~6 character-long (alpha + numbers)
- max number of documents: 10,000
- low probability risk of collision is acceptable
- easy to implement in AWS Lambda (python)

I am looking for an algorithm, python library or function that can solve this problem.

If this problem has not been solved before, my question would be what is the probability of collision if I use say first 6 characters of MD5?

PS: I tried smalz library, but it required dependencies I could not install on work laptop.

Comment: So far you described your goal/requirements, but there is no question here. Are you looking for recommendation for a library (off-topic)? What have you tried (show your code) and ask question about specific problem.

Comment: @buran, thank you for valuable feedback updated my Question:

" I am looking for an algorithm, python library or function that can solve this problem.

If this problem has not been solved before, my question would be what is the probability of collision if I use say first 6 characters of MD5?"

Comment: _am looking for an algorithm, python library or function that can solve this problem_: check [help/on-topic]: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You can always just take the first few bytes of the hash in the same way that Git shortens its SHA-1 sums for commits. The chance of collisions should follow the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), I think